# How can I disable JpaAudit when there is no user logged in?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, audit

I use JpaAudit in my app.
It works fine, but when there is no user authenticated
and I try to add something o the database I have an error.
Is it possible to disable JpaAuditing when there is no user authenticated?

Here is my configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.teamcompetencymatrix.www"})
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaAuditing
    public class AuditConfig {
    
    private final UserService userService;

    public AuditConfig(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<User> auditorProvider() {
        return new AuditorAwareImpl(userService);
    }

    }
```